# R: Multiple Variables defined in column?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hello and good evening,

I do have a problem with a dataset that I can't seem to solve, even though I tried for hours in R.

Here is the minimum working example.

```
library(tidyverse)

mytibble <- tribble(
  ~shopid, ~oldvarname , ~postcode1, ~postcode2, ~postcode3,
  "A"    , "postcode"  , "A110"    , "B220", "Z112",
  "A"    , "itemssold" , "10"      , "20"    ,"30",
  "B"    , "postcode"  , "A214"    , "C112", NA,
  "B"    , "itemssold" , "15"      , "20"    , NA,
  "C"    , "postcode"  , "A221"    , NA    , NA,
  "C"    , "itemssold" , "4"       , NA    , NA)
```

As one can see, two variables ("postcode" and "itemssold") are defined within the variable "oldvarname". Variables values can then be inferred from the variables postcode1 through postcodex.

Here is my desired end result:

```
goal <- tribble(
  ~shopid, ~postcode, ~itemssold,
  "A"    , "A110"   , 10,
  "A"    , "B220"   , 20, 
  "A"    , "Z112"   , 30,
  "B"    , "A214"   , 15,
  "B"    , "C112"   , 20,
  "C"    , "A221"   , 4)
```

I tried to reach my goal by working with pivot_wider() and pivot_longer() (or a combination) from the tidyverse, but couldn't seem to solve my problem.

I would be indefinitely grateful for any helpful comments.

Thank you very much in advance,

Minimouse

Comment: Not sure if you are stuck on tidyverse or not, but there are some fairly detailed vignettes for data.table, illustrating how to switch from long format to wide format, see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

mytibble <- tribble(
  ~shopid, ~oldvarname , ~postcode1, ~postcode2, ~postcode3,
  "A"    , "postcode"  , "A110"    , "B220", "Z112",
  "A"    , "itemssold" , "10"      , "20"    ,"30",
  "B"    , "postcode"  , "A214"    , "C112", NA,
  "B"    , "itemssold" , "15"      , "20"    , NA,
  "C"    , "postcode"  , "A221"    , NA    , NA,
  "C"    , "itemssold" , "4"       , NA    , NA)

df1 <- mytibble %>% 
  filter(oldvarname=="postcode") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("postcode"),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "postcode"
  ) %>% 
  select(-oldvarname, -names) %>% 
  drop_na()

df2 <- mytibble %>% 
  filter(oldvarname=="itemssold") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("postcode"),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "itemssold"
  ) %>%  
  select(-oldvarname, -names) %>% 
  drop_na()

df1$itemssold <- df2$itemssold
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your approach. I had a similar approach in mind, but somehow got lost along the way ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

you can try

```
mytibble %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1:-2, names_prefix ="postcode") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = oldvarname, values_from = value) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  shopid name  postcode itemssold
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    
1 A      1     A110     10       
2 A      2     B220     20       
3 A      3     Z112     30       
4 B      1     A214     15       
5 B      2     C112     20       
6 C      1     A221     4
```

Comment: The name column should be removed in your tibble. With this line in your code my code may appear a little less awkward. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for this smart solution to my problem. I learned at lot. Thanks again :-)